# Mapping between resource file and model object in Eclipse plugin app

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Please anyone help me understand and use `IDE.openEditor(IWorkbenchPage, IFile)`.

I have a resource file (xml format), it contains my model objects. I'm writing a wizard to create it, save it into workspace, view it inside a tree view (I use CommonNavigator) and open it in an editor. I need to know the control flow of this all. How to map between resource file and model objects, how the navigator can show that objects and how to open editor that associated with my resource file.

I'm sorry, I'm a newbie in Eclipse field. I know I need too much, but please give me at least an idea.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

A great character once said... "You have much to learn young padawan".

Here's a great place to start your journey though the basics of Eclipse plug-in / RCP development...

http://www.vogella.com/eclipse.html

If you really want to get down and dirty into the bowels of Eclipse, you can use Eclipse itself to teach you the dirty details about what's really going on.

1. Figure out how to view Eclipse source code inside of Eclipse.
2. Set break points at interesting points in Eclipse source code that you want to know more about.
3. Use the 'Eclipse Application' run configuration to run an instance of Eclipse from within your main Eclipse.
4. Use your newly launched Eclipse to preform the tasks you want to mimic and hopefully, you'll hit one of your break points and see how the Eclipse developers did what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks Twindham, I solved the problem. Now I understand the Eclipse framework and I can work with it. Thank again.

Comment: @nautilusvn: can you share your experience/solution?